# Linq Include not working

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this linq expression

```
ActionPlan
    .Include(x => x.Goal)
    .Include(x => x.Responsibles)
    .Include(x => x.Goal.EducationalPlan)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.State == State.Active && x.Goal.State == State.Active && x.Goal.EducationalPlan.State == State.Active)
    .Where(x => x.Responsibles.Any(r => r.PersonId == pes_id))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => x.Goal)
    .ToList();
```

The include of EducationalPlan is not working, why? All other work normaly,
EducationPlan is a object not a list.

Comment: is `goal` a collection?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Are you sure there is an EducationalPlan associated with that goal?

Answer (score 2):

For multiple levels you should go like this:

```
ActionPlan
    .Include(x => x.Goal)
    .Include(x => x.Responsibles)
    .Include(x => x.Goal.Select(y => y.EducationalPlan))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.State == State.Active && x.Goal.State == State.Active && x.Goal.EducationalPlan.State == State.Active)
    .Where(x => x.Responsibles.Any(r => r.PersonId == pes_id))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => x.Goal)
    .ToList();
```

Or try this:

```
ActionPlan
    .Include(x => x.Goal)
    .Include(x => x.Responsibles)
    .Include("Goal.EducationalPlan")
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.State == State.Active && x.Goal.State == State.Active && x.Goal.EducationalPlan.State == State.Active)
    .Where(x => x.Responsibles.Any(r => r.PersonId == pes_id))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => x.Goal)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What makes you think that `Goal` is a collection?

Comment: this .Include("Goal.EducationalPlan") should have worked!